# How to calculate corner coordinates of static Google Map image using PHP?

Tags: google-maps, php

How can I calculate the corner coordinates of a static Google Map image, like the one fetched with this **[URL](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=34.065174,-118.254304&zoom=6&size=640x640&scale=2&sensor=false)**, using a little PHP script?

Comment: You will find a similar thread here (in javascript) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12507274/how-to-get-bounds-of-a-google-static-map